# requests AttributeError: type object 'bytes' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have created a program that parses the famous `API` from 2ip. The problem arises even when, then the receiving argument was assigned both `bytes` and `str`, nothing helps, here is the code:

```
View_dict = {
        'View':{
            'txt':  [
                    'text', 'txt', 'log', 'TXT', 'LOG'
                    ],
            'str':  [
                    'str', 'STR', 'out'
                    ]
        }
    }   



class Main:
    class BreakHost:
        domain = bytes
        mode = str
        def __init__(self, Mode, Domain, load_proxy=bytes):
            self.domain=Domain
            self.mode=Mode
            try:
                for k, v in View_dict["View"].items():
                    if Mode in v:
                        Mode = k
                send_requests = requests.get(f'https://api.2ip.ua/hosting.json?site={Domain}', proxies=load_proxy)
                answer = send_requests
                soup_check = bs4.BeautifulSoup(answer, 'lxml')
                error_send = soup_check.find('div', class_='error').text.strip()
                if error_send == 'IP address is not valid / IP-адрес не действительный':
                    if Mode == 'txt':
                        _error_(View=Mode, TEXT='This is Domain does not exist', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='CRITICAL', TypeMSG='Message')
                        return Sos1skaError(f'Domain not exist, check the entered domain ---> {Domain}')
                    elif Mode == 'str':
                        _error_(View=Mode, TEXT='This is Domain does not exist', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='CRITICAL', TypeMSG='Message')
                        return Sos1skaError(f'Domain not exist, check the entered doamin ---> {Domain}')
                else:
                    pass
                soup_json = bs4.BeautifulSoup(send_requests).text.strip()
                site_json = json.loads(soup_json)
                Handler = site_json
                if Mode == 'str':
                    try:
                        _info_(View='str', TEXT='%s' % (Handler["name_ripe"]), NickName=Root)
                    except KeyError:
                        _info_(View='str', TEXT='Not Found Information', NickName=Root)
                    try:
                        _info_(View='str', TEXT='%s' % (Handler["name_rus"]), NickName=Root)
                    except KeyError:
                        _info_(View='str', TEXT='Not Found Information', NickName=Root)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                _warning_(View='str', TEXT='KeyboardInterrupt', NickName=Root, TypeMSG='Message')
                time.sleep(2)
                _error_(View='str', TEXT='KeyboardInterrupt', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='WARNING', TypeMSG='Message')
                return Sos1skaKeyboardInterrupt('Keyboardinterrupt, pressed "CTRL+C"')
```

P.S. I did not find a solution to the problem on the Internet

Full Error:

```
File "d:\Development\S_B_FrameWork\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    Main.BreakHost(Mode='str', Domain='google.com')
  File "d:\Development\S_B_FrameWork\services\__init__.py", line 65, in __init__
    send_requests = requests.get(f'https://api.2ip.ua/hosting.json?site={Domain}', proxies=load_proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Kolia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kolia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kolia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 532, in request
    settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
  File "C:\Users\Kolia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 710, in merge_environment_settings
    no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: type object 'bytes' has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please add your full error. This will help us find where is it faster.

Comment: I have added the complete error

Comment: Why do you define "bytes" as default for parameter "load_proxy"? What should this do?

Comment: GOD!!! I found my mistake. I did not think that the problem would affect the load_proxy argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Main:
    class BreakHost:
        domain = bytes
        mode = str
        def __init__(self, Mode, Domain, load_proxy=None):
            self.domain=Domain
            self.mode=Mode
            try:
                for k, v in View_dict["View"].items():
                    if Mode in v:
                        Mode = k
                if load_proxy == None:
                    send_requests = requests.get(f'https://api.2ip.ua/hosting.json?site={Domain}')
                    answer = send_requests
                    soup_check = bs4.BeautifulSoup(answer.text, 'html.parser')
                    error_send = soup_check.find('div', class_='error')
                    if error_send == 'IP address is not valid / IP-адрес не действительный':
                        if Mode == 'txt':
                            _error_(View=Mode, TEXT='This is Domain does not exist', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='CRITICAL', TypeMSG='Message')
                            return Sos1skaError(f'Domain not exist, check the entered domain ---> {Domain}')
                        elif Mode == 'str':
                            _error_(View=Mode, TEXT='This is Domain does not exist', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='CRITICAL', TypeMSG='Message')
                            return Sos1skaError(f'Domain not exist, check the entered doamin ---> {Domain}')
                    else:
                        pass
                    soup_json = bs4.BeautifulSoup(send_requests.text, 'html.parser').text
                    site_json = json.loads(soup_json)
                    Handler = site_json
                    if Mode == 'str':
                        try:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='%s' % (Handler["name_ripe"]), NickName=Root)
                        except KeyError:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='Not Found Information', NickName=Root)
                        try:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='%s' % (Handler["name_rus"]), NickName=Root)
                        except KeyError:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='Not Found Information', NickName=Root)
                else:
                    send_requests = requests.get(f'https://api.2ip.ua/hosting.json?site={Domain}', proxies=load_proxy)
                    answer = send_requests
                    soup_check = bs4.BeautifulSoup(answer.text, 'html.parser')
                    error_send = soup_check.find('div', class_='error')
                    if error_send == 'IP address is not valid / IP-адрес не действительный':
                        if Mode == 'txt':
                            _error_(View=Mode, TEXT='This is Domain does not exist', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='CRITICAL', TypeMSG='Message')
                            return Sos1skaError(f'Domain not exist, check the entered domain ---> {Domain}')
                        elif Mode == 'str':
                            _error_(View=Mode, TEXT='This is Domain does not exist', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='CRITICAL', TypeMSG='Message')
                            return Sos1skaError(f'Domain not exist, check the entered doamin ---> {Domain}')
                    else:
                        pass
                    soup_json = bs4.BeautifulSoup(send_requests.text, 'html.parser').text
                    site_json = json.loads(soup_json)
                    Handler = site_json
                    if Mode == 'str':
                        try:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='%s' % (Handler["name_ripe"]), NickName=Root)
                        except KeyError:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='Not Found Information', NickName=Root)
                        try:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='%s' % (Handler["name_rus"]), NickName=Root)
                        except KeyError:
                            _info_(View='str', TEXT='Not Found Information', NickName=Root)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                _warning_(View='str', TEXT='KeyboardInterrupt', NickName=Root, TypeMSG='Message')
                time.sleep(2)
                _error_(View='str', TEXT='KeyboardInterrupt', NickName=Root, Sender='BreakHost', TypeError='WARNING', TypeMSG='Message')
                return Sos1skaKeyboardInterrupt('Keyboardinterrupt, pressed "CTRL+C"')
```

The error was in load_proxy, and I understood why I was passing bytes to it as an argument. Thanks to `Michael Butscher` for the note and the question about the `load_proxy` argument